# Comparing different stereochemistry terms

Tags: stereochemistry

What is the difference between:

1. Meso compound and an optically inactive compound
2. Chiral compound and an optically active compound

For all examples i have seen, chiral compounds were optically active and meso were optically inactive so is there any difference between them?

Comment: Meso is only a subtype of optically inactive compounds and chirality doesn't guarantee noticeable optical activity.

Comment: "A meso compound is an optically inactive member of a set of stereoisomers, at least two of which are optically active."  See: The Meaning of Meso", J. Chem. Educ., 2008, 85, 441.

Comment: What was the reason behind all these downvotes??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meso compounds have a chiral centre , but they also have a plane of symmetry making them optically inactive....or u can say meso compounds are optically inactive due to internal compensation.

Whereas enantiomers taken  together ie. formation of racemic mixture (50:50) is optically inactive as a whole due to external compensation.(They can be optically active individually)

Therefore chirality isn't the only defination for the optical activity of a compound, there are reasons such as symmetry to account for as well.